# Why is this function not returning any values?

Tags: python, algorithm

Each sub-list always has three elements in the following order:

1. Type of membership: a string that is one of `'Student'`, `'Faculty'` or `'Visitor'`.
2. Type of car: a string that is one of `'Coupe'`, `'Sedan'`, `'SUV'` or `'Hybrid'`.
3. Duration: the number of hours the car was borrowed for
   The cars provide free service for up to certain number of hours based on the type of membership:
4. `'Student'`: ﬁrst three hours are free
5. `'Faculty'`: ﬁrst two hours are free
6. `'Visitor'`: ﬁrst hour is free

After free service is over, the members are charged based on the type of car they have rented:

- Sedan: $10 per hour
- Coupe: $12 per hour
- SUV: $13 per hour
- Hybrid: $15 per hour

At index 0 store the total income generated by Sedans. At index 1 store the total income generated by Coupes. At index 2 store the total income generated by SUVs. At index 3 store the total income generated by Hybrids.

```
def car_rental(rentals):
    car_type = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Student' and car_type == "Sedan" and hours > 3:
            income = 10 * (hours - 3)
            car_type[0] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Faculty' and car_type == "Sedan" and hours > 2:
           income = 10 * (hours - 2)
           car_type[0] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Visitor' and car_type == "Sedan" and hours > 1:
            income = 10 * (hours - 1)
            car_type[0] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Student' and car_type == "Coupe" and hours > 3:
           income = 12 * (hours - 3)
           car_type[1] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Faculty' and car_type == "Coupe" and hours > 2:
           income = 12 * (hours - 2)
           car_type[1] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Visitor' and car_type == "Coupe" and hours > 1:
           income = 12 * (hours - 1)
           car_type[1] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Student' and car_type == "SUV" and hours > 3:
           income = 13 * (hours - 3)
           car_type[2] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Faculty' and car_type == "SUV" and hours > 2:
           income = 13 * (hours - 2)
           car_type[2] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Visitor' and car_type == "SUV" and hours > 1:
           income = 13 * (hours - 1)
           car_type[2] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Student' and car_type == "Hybrid" and hours > 3:
           income = 15 * (hours - 3)
           car_type[3] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Faculty' and car_type == "Hybrid" and hours > 2:
           income = 15 * (hours - 2)
           car_type[3] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental == 'Visitor' and car_type == "Hybrid" and hours > 1:
           income = 15 * (hours - 1)
           car_type[3] += income

    return car_type
```

Tested with:

```
print("Testing car_rental() with rentals = [['Student','Coupe',4],['Faculty','Coupe',4],['Visitor','Coupe',4]]: " +
      str(car_rental([['Student', 'Coupe', 4], ['Faculty', 'Coupe', 4], ['Visitor', 'Coupe', 4]])))
print("Testing car_rental() with rentals = [['Student','Coupe',4],['Faculty','SUV',4],['Visitor','Hybrid',4],['Visitor','Sedan',4]]: " +
      str(car_rental([['Student', 'Coupe', 4], ['Faculty', 'SUV', 4], ['Visitor', 'Hybrid', 4], ['Visitor', 'Sedan', 4]])))
print("Testing car_rental() with rentals = [['Student','Coupe',3],['Faculty','SUV',2],['Visitor','Hybrid',1],['Visitor','Sedan',4]]: " +
      str(car_rental([['Student', 'Coupe', 3], ['Faculty', 'SUV', 2], ['Visitor', 'Hybrid', 1], ['Visitor', 'Sedan', 4]])))
print()
```

Comment: Can i ask why you just didn't do one single loop ?

Comment: Have not learned it yet, I'm just starting out and this is my first class

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at your lecture notes because there are so much things wrong in your code that you will most likely not find anyone to help you here. Especially take a look at for loops and arrays. If you haven't here them already, I suggest you take the time to look at it or wait for a next class

Comment: car_type is an array of incomes that is suppose to be output in a format [1,2,3,4] where the first 0 is the income of the sedans, the second 0 would be the income of the coupes and so on

Comment: I would recommend naming variables, arrays, etc a bit more descriptively. They should at the very least not confuse what it is that they are or what they do? `car_type_income` would be a bit clearer. With that, look at your loops and at switch/case. You only need one loop to iterate through your rentals, and you need to make sure you're passing in the things you need to your function (I'm assuming rental is some sort of structure of rental, car_type, hours, etc). If so, try to prevent naming different things the same. Avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you're referencing the elements of the `rentals` argument passed to the function. Specifically in each of the `for rental in rentals:` loops, the `rental` variable itself is also a `list` and you need to reference its contents with the `[]` indexing notation.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
def car_rental(rentals):
    car_type = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Student' and rental[1] == "Sedan" and rental[2] > 3:
            income = 10 * (rental[2] - 3)
            car_type[0] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Faculty' and rental[1] == "Sedan" and rental[2] > 2:
           income = 10 * (rental[2] - 2)
           car_type[0] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Visitor' and rental[1] == "Sedan" and rental[2] > 1:
            income = 10 * (rental[2] - 1)
            car_type[0] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Student' and rental[1] == "Coupe" and rental[2] > 3:
           income = 12 * (rental[2] - 3)
           car_type[1] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Faculty' and rental[1] == "Coupe" and rental[2] > 2:
           income = 12 * (rental[2] - 2)
           car_type[1] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Visitor' and rental[1] == "Coupe" and rental[2] > 1:
           income = 12 * (rental[2] - 1)
           car_type[1] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Student' and rental[1] == "SUV" and rental[2] > 3:
           income = 13 * (rental[2] - 3)
           car_type[2] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Faculty' and rental[1] == "SUV" and rental[2] > 2:
           income = 13 * (rental[2] - 2)
           car_type[2] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Visitor' and rental[1] == "SUV" and rental[2] > 1:
           income = 13 * (rental[2] - 1)
           car_type[2] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Student' and rental[1] == "Hybrid" and rental[2] > 3:
           income = 15 * (rental[2] - 3)
           car_type[3] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Faculty' and rental[1] == "Hybrid" and rental[2] > 2:
           income = 15 * (rental[2] - 2)
           car_type[3] += income
    for rental in rentals:
        if rental[0] == 'Visitor' and rental[1] == "Hybrid" and rental[2] > 1:
           income = 15 * (rental[2] - 1)
           car_type[3] += income

    return car_type

print("Testing car_rental() with rentals = "
      "[['Student','Coupe',4], ['Faculty','Coupe',4], ['Visitor','Coupe',4]]: " +
      str(car_rental([['Student', 'Coupe', 4], ['Faculty', 'Coupe', 4], ['Visitor', 'Coupe', 4]])))

print("Testing car_rental() with rentals = "
      "[['Student','Coupe',4], ['Faculty','SUV',4], ['Visitor','Hybrid',4], ['Visitor','Sedan',4]]: " +
      str(car_rental([['Student', 'Coupe', 4], ['Faculty', 'SUV', 4], ['Visitor', 'Hybrid', 4], ['Visitor', 'Sedan', 4]])))

print("Testing car_rental() with rentals = "
      "[['Student','Coupe',3],['Faculty','SUV',2],['Visitor','Hybrid',1],['Visitor','Sedan',4]]: " +
      str(car_rental([['Student', 'Coupe', 3], ['Faculty', 'SUV', 2], ['Visitor', 'Hybrid', 1], ['Visitor', 'Sedan', 4]])))
```

Output:

`Testing car_rental() with rentals = [['Student','Coupe',4], ['Faculty','Coupe',4], ['Visitor','Coupe',4]]: [0, 72, 0, 0]`

`Testing car_rental() with rentals = [['Student','Coupe',4], ['Faculty','SUV',4], ['Visitor','Hybrid',4], ['Visitor','Sedan',4]]: [30, 12, 26, 45]`

`Testing car_rental() with rentals = [['Student','Coupe',3],['Faculty','SUV',2],['Visitor','Hybrid',1],['Visitor','Sedan',4]]: [30, 0, 0, 0]`

A better way to fix it would be to give readable names to each of the elements of the `rental` sublists at the beginning of each nested `for` loop. Something along these lines:

```
def car_rental(rentals):
    car_type = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for customer, style, hours in rentals:
        if customer == 'Student' and style == "Sedan" and hours > 3:
            income = 10 * (hours - 3)
            car_type[0] += income
    for customer, style, hours in rentals:
        if customer == 'Faculty' and style == "Sedan" and hours > 2:
           income = 10 * (hours - 2)
           car_type[0] += income
    etc ...
```

Beyond that you could also put all the `if` statements inside one big `for rental in rentals:` loop. This would be faster and shorten the amount of code needed slightly:

```
def car_rental(rentals):
    car_type = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for customer, style, hours in rentals:
        if customer == 'Student' and style == "Sedan" and hours > 3:
            income = 10 * (hours - 3)
            car_type[0] += income

        if customer == 'Faculty' and style == "Sedan" and hours > 2:
           income = 10 * (hours - 2)
           car_type[0] += income

        etc ...
```

Comment: Thank you and I see what I did wrong, and thank your for showing me the correction.